# BlackBerry 10: GNU STL

Tags: c++, qt, stl, blackberry-10, gnu

I am trying to create a BB10 cascades project with Momentics IDE version 2.0 and I need the project to use the GNU Standard library instead of Dinkumware (because I have external libs compiled with `arm-unknown-nto-qnx8.0.0eabi-g++` that only supports gnu std).

In the IDE, I have changed Project Properties->C/C++ Build/Settings/Runtime to "C++ GNU with exceptions". However, when I run a simple project with a static library (.a file) created by me (with just a header file containing a constructor, `std::string` object, setter and getter (for the object) and the corresponding cpp file), I get a segmentation fault when I do this:

```
testnamespace::testclass *object = new testnamespace::testclass();

std::string test = "Hello";
object->setText(test);

delete object;
```

I think this error occurs because the library was compiled with gnu std and the project is compiled with Dinkumware.

I verified the include paths, and I found out that

```
C:\bbndk\target_10_1_0_428\qnx6\usr\include
```

is included before

```
C:\bbndk\target_10_1_0_428\qnx6\usr\include\c++\4.6.3
```

Also, the command used by the makefile to compile the cpp files in the project is `qcc -Vgcc_ntoarmv7le` instead of `qcc -V4.6.3,gcc_ntoarmv7le_gpp` (support flag for gnu stl).

Am I doing something wrong? Some configuration is missing?

I really need to use GNU STD instead of Dinkumware in my BlackBerry project, but I can't figure out how to do it.

**EDIT:**

I have made some changes in my project and I fixed some issues.

I added this to my .pro file

```
QMAKE_CXX = qcc -V4.6.3,gcc_ntoarmv7le_gpp
QMAKE_CC = qcc -V4.6.3,gcc_ntoarmv7le
QMAKE_LINK = qcc -V4.6.3,gcc_ntoarmv7le_gpp
QMAKE_AS = qcc -V4.6.3,gcc_ntoarmv7le_gpp

LIBS += -lc -lm -lcpp -lstdc++ -Bstatic ../libs/libteste.a -Bdynamic
```

(LIBS command was already there of course, but I decided to put it here so you can understand how I am linking the libs).

Now, I have the following code:

```
testenamespace::TesteClass *temp = new testenamespace::TesteClass() ;

std::string teste = "Hello";

temp->setTesteString(teste);

QString qsr = QString::fromStdString(temp->getTesteString());


qDebug ("String in the object: "+qsr.toLatin1());

delete temp;
```

Everything works fine, until the code reaches `delete temp;` where I am getting the output:

> Qml debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment! String in the object: Hello  Process 1173778674 (test_bb10) terminated
>   SIGSEGV code=2 fltno=11
>   ip=0150ed7c(/usr/lib/ldqnx.so.2@_list_release+0x3c) mapaddr=0002ed7c.
>   ref=78362e2b

and sometimes I get

> Qml debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment! String in the object: Hello free malloc object that is not
>   allocated:../../dlist.c:1096**

I think that the problem is in `new` and `delete` invocations, maybe the standard library imported by the processor is not the right one.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by moving my project to Ubuntu. Momentics for Windows doesn't work well with GNU C++ as runtime.